# Scroll images at bottom of page

Tags: html, scroll

1. I need to create a webpage with images at bottom of the page of 50 px height and the top of the page will be blog/text.
2. Users should be able to scroll the images left or right at bottom and when they click on the photos it would zoom into the photo from the blog.
3. The photos will load as the user scrolls left and right at bottom div.

Example :

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Yosemite+National+Park/@37.74145,-119.59168,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m8!1e2!3m6!1s15587532!2e1!3e10!6s%2F%2Fstorage.googleapis.com%2Fstatic.panoramio.com%2Fphotos%2Fsmall%2F15587532.jpg!7i1536!8i2048!4m2!3m1!1s0x8096f09df58aecc5:0x2d249c2ced8003fe!6m1!1e1

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: Show us some code? We are here to help you, not to build the application for you.

Comment: @Stanimir : its ok. Thanks for your critics!

Comment: @m02ph3u5 : Sorry i missed to add the question. I need some pointers to where should I start. Visualife has suggested to work with ligthbox example. So i will try that. Will post a followup once i write a piece of code. And like I mentioned... I am new to HTML, Javascript and CSS. Kindly be considerate and I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you post code then we can help better, but if you haven't written any yet then it's worth checking out something like the following link (there's a plethora out there)

The zoom you're talking about is normally referred to as lightbox (darken or lightened background behind the image)

[lightbox example](https://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-lightbox-plugin-image-gallery/)

You also seem to be describing 2 things:
 - a horizontal gallery display in the footer
 - an image clicked from within a blog

if you've built a blog then you should check out the associated docs (assuming you've utilised something like Wordpress) as they'll likely already have a solution or plugin available.

Comment: thank you! I will try this and next time ask a right question :) I am currently creating HTML templates/pages and will be writing the code from scratch in python/Django.

Comment: I appreciate your input!